# Image search using google api

Tags: image

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=apple+icon

Am using the above API to get the set of images for my search keyword.
The API return exact results for my search keyword. But what i want is, to limit the search images size and color.

Is it possible to send image size and image color as a parameter to the API call.
I have searched for the documentation but all in vain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Google's API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide):

Optional URl arguments:

**imgsz**

```
imgsz=icon

Restricts the search to images of the specified size, where size can be one of:

imgsz=icon restricts results to small images
imgsz=small|medium|large|xlarge restricts results to medium-sized images
imgsz=xxlarge restricts results to large images
imgsz=huge restricts resykts to extra-large images
```

And for colour (**imgcolor**) just above that...